# iife returned function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, iife

I'm trying to create a module, and I'm trying to use the correct design. I saw [this library](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/blob/master/Sortable.js), and they had a iife returning the `function` that's a module. I tried doing that like this:

```js
(function() {
  function MyModule() {
    var something = 'something';
    this.log = log();
  }

  MyModule.prototype.alert = function() {
    alert(this.something);
  };

  function log() {
    console.log('hello');
  }

  return MyModule;
})();

var module1 = new MyModule();
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MyModule is not defined

Here's the relevant copied code:

- [Start](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/blob/master/Sortable.js#L24)
- [Main Function](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/blob/master/Sortable.js#L180)
- [End / return](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/blob/master/Sortable.js#L1276)

What am i doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to assign what IIFE returns to a `MyModule` variable

Comment: aand why would you define it in iife if you want to access the function globally? That is what they are designed to prevent lol..

Comment: @SugatoSengupta to make a function `log` 
"private"? (it does not bring any benefits here though).

Comment: huh okay I get it.. How about using classes then? Hoping this is not a singleton.

Comment: @SugatoSengupta Classes will not help: in JS there is no way to make something inaccessible other than using IIFE/ES2015 modules.

Comment: dunno may be.. I think this one is unnecessary anyway.. Users can see the implementation of log anyway. Making it private won't help.

Comment: @SugatoSengupta well, it's not about making it "invisible", since you cannot. It's about making stuff private.

Comment: well ofcourse.. It's client side code anyway.. I havent really tried the private stuffs the `private` way yet. Not sure why I need it, but that's out of the context :)

Comment: @SugatoSengupta `var counter = (() => { let cnt = 0; return () => ++cnt; })();` here is the example. It's a counter function with locally scoped counter value which you cannot mess with even if you want.

Comment: what is this? ES6? Sorry I can't recognise it i am too slow lol

Comment: @SugatoSengupta That's ecmascript 6. It isn't too difficult to understand if you know ecmascript 5. Just look up the references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyModule` is staying inside the IIFE clousure so it wont be visible from code outside. Assign the result  of the IIFE to a `MyModule` variable

Also, you probably meant to assign the `log` function to the `MyModule` being constructed, and not its result (`undefined`)

And finally, the fact that you declare a variable called `something` in the constructor does not assign it as a property of the object being constructed. If you wanted `something` to be private, you have to declare the `alert` method inside the clousure of the constructor:

```
var MyModule = (function() {
  function MyModule() {
    var something = 'something';
    this.log = log;
    // this.log = log();

    this.alert = function() {
        alert(something);
    };
  }

  //MyModule.prototype.alert = function() {
  //    alert(this.something);
  //};

  function log() {
    console.log('hello');
  }

  return MyModule;
})();

var module1 = new MyModule();

module1.alert(); // Alerts 'something'
module1.log(); // Logs 'hello'
```

To really understand JavaScript, forget about classes, learn about prototypes and functions in general, specially clousures.

Watch this [brilliant conference by Douglas Crockford](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM) to get it right.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that might be the problem, but when I checked the library posted in the question, they didn't do `var MyModule = (function() {`, they just did `return`, without the assignment.

Comment: In that library they assign the variable as global variable by assigning it to the window object: `window["Sortable"] = factory();` , check line 22. This is the same as `Sortable = ...`.

Comment: oh. I actually didn't know what the 3 if statements were doing. I was going to check what it does when I finished my project. Is it better using `Sortable = ...` or making the variable global? Isn't it safer not making it global? But I see with most librarys, they have the 3 if statements, so I'm not sure which is better

Comment: It is safer not making it global, but it depends on the environment. This libraries are prepared to work as modules if the enviroment supports that, but in the case of the browser, they have to rely on global variables.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do with this module, but based on how it looks. This will always log hello and it sets up an alert function that alerts 'something'.

```
var MyModule = (function() {
    var something = 'something';

  this.prototype.alert = function() {
    alert(this.something);
  };

    console.log('hello');
})();

var module1 = new MyModule();
```

However if you want to set this up to pass different things to alert and log you should be able to do it this way.

```
var MyModule = (function( txt ) {
    var something = this.txt;

  this.prototype.alert = function() {
    alert(something);
  };

    console.log('hello '+ something);
})();

var module1 = new MyModule();
   module1('this is awesome text');
```